# When launching Appium, I get the following error: "ERROR: main.js: error: Unrecognized arguments

Tags: appium

When launching Appium, I get the following error:

> ERROR: main.js: error: Unrecognized arguments:
>   SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4.2\LiftMaster_stg3_06132014.apk.

Running on a windowns 7 machine with a Android 4.4 connected and have Appium installed with node.js. Please help!

Comment: Could you post the `main.js` code...

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how do I post the main.js code?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding quotation marks around the (Application path) because my **windows username had a space** in it.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because (if you're starting Appium from the command line) you're not passing the argument `--app` before the path to your .apk file.

```
$ appium path\to\app.apk
appium: error: Unrecognized arguments: path\to\app.apk.
```

versus the working:

```
$ appium --app path\to\app.apk
info: Welcome to Appium v1.1.0 (REV e433bbc31511f199287db7724e1ce692bcb32117)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
info: socket.io started
info: Non-default server args: {"app":"path\to\app.apk"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because my apk is place in **folder with space**. Remove space work for me @@

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. There is a solution that can launch appium (UI) without error `main.js`

> error: Unrecognized arguments.

1. Appium-General Setting-Logging, make sure "Quite Logging" isn't checked.
2. You can set and save your log on your Desktop( or other directories).

Then try to launch and run your appium script again. In my laptop, it can work well.

Answer (score -1):

Even I had faced the same issue.

Try saving your `apk` on desktop and then give its path. It will work fine.